# Conditional statement using accessor methods in Java

Tags: java

my `_holder.getColor()` is supposed to return the color RED by default and these conditional statements are not working. I think I have the syntax wrong.

Basically I want to be able to highlight a paintswatch when I click on it, and if the swatch color is the same as the one in `ColorHolder`, I want it to deselect the swatch.

```
import wheels.users.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class PaintSwatch extends Ellipse
{
    private ColorHolder _holder; 
    public int _i;

    public PaintSwatch(Color c,ColorHolder holder){
        super(c);
        _holder = holder;
        _i = 1;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if (_holder.getColor() != super.getColor()){
            super.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
            super.setFrameThickness(3);
            _holder.setColor(super.getColor());
        }

        if (_holder.getColor() == super.getColor()){
            super.setFrameThickness(10);
            super.setFrameColor(Color.WHITE);
            _holder.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ColorHolder Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class ColorHolder implements Colorable
{
    private Color _currentColor;

    public ColorHolder()
    {
        _currentColor = Color.RED;
    }

    public Color getColor(){
        return _currentColor;
    }

    public void setColor(Color c){
        _currentColor = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `equals()` instead of `==`. You're comparing objects of type `Color`..

Comment: hey, thanks! would this be correct ? if(_holder.getColor.equals(super.getColor())){...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using equals you should also use an if else instead of two distinct ifs :

```
if (_holder.getColor() != super.getColor()) {
   ...
   _holder.setColor(super.getColor());
}

if (_holder.getColor() == super.getColor()) { 
   ...
}
```

Note that the second if condition will always evaluate to true - if the holder's color is not equal to super's color, it will be set in the first if condition.

```
if (_holder.getColor().equals(super.getColor())) {
   ... do sth
} else {
   ... do sth else
}
```

Also make sure that either the holder and super do not return null as color or check it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Within `PaintSwatch` class replace

```
if (_holder.getColor() != super.getColor())
```

to

```
if (!_holder.getColor().equals(super.getColor()))
```

Comment: hey if I wanted one swatch to be selected at a time, could I create a public int _i=0; and have a 2 conditional if statement? ex) ... if (!_holder.getColor().equals(super.getColor()) && _i ==0) {. ...  at the end i'll have: _i=1 }

Comment: Couldnot get your question..can u elaborate it more.?